# PHP: stream remote pdf to client browser

Tags: php, stream

there's a pdf generated on an external service and I would like to stream the pdf to the browser in my php server while streaming to client so that I don't need to download the pdf from the remote file and then start initializing download. I would just have the file immediately download or stream to the client requesting it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming that the generated pdf is in http://bar.com/foo.pdf, you could do:

```
  $data = file_get_contents("http://bar.com/foo.pdf");
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=YOURFILE.pdf");

  echo $data;
```

Comment: this is what I used instead of of `fopen("php://");`

Comment: It is better to use `readfile` rather than loading the PDF file into memory http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: What's the difference between 'application/octet-stream" and "application/pdf"?

Comment: @Alan application/octet-stream is for attachment while application/pdf is for display inline (without download)

Answer (score -1):

Even this is an old question but I found it when looking for something else, so, my response is for next visitors

To render a pdf file as stream use the Header:

```
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=YOURFILE.pdf");
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition