# Downloading PDF to Browser

Tags: php

I have a PHP web application. I have built a function to download a PDF from an API end point like this:

```
public function importPdf($id)
{
    $resource = fopen('tmp/'.$id.'.pdf', 'w');

    $this->client->request('GET', $this->url . '/api/users/' . $id . '/pdf', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => "Bearer {$this->accessToken()}",
        ],
        'sink' => $resource,
    ]);
}
```

This is calling a Guzzle instance which is working fine and is saving the PDF file to my server. But what I need is for the PDF file to be downloaded to the users browser. If anyone could explain how this can be done I would be grateful.

Comment: Either you save it in a directory which is accessible by the web server, or you stream it giving an appropriate http header (which is, IMHO, a bit too broad to answer here).

Comment: Anyway, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847015/php-stream-remote-pdf-to-client-browser#16847068), it might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this sort of what your looking for? I use this to allow users to download certain files from their browser.

```
public function functionNameHere($filename){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($filename); 
}
```